# More concise LINQ with 'or' clause

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a small LINQ query containing a Where clause; something like:

```
    var blueRedGreenBikes = GetBikes(filter)
.Where(a => a.Color == "Blue" || a.Color == "Red" || a.Color == "Green")
.Count()
```

I am looking for a way to write this type of query more concisely using LINQ. In SQL, I might write a similar WHERE clause like:

```
WHERE bike.Color IN ('Red','Blue','Green')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the LINQ [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.100).aspx) method to check your item's color against a collection.

```
var colorList=new List<string> { "Blue","Red","Green"};

var blueRedGreenBikes = GetBikes(filter).Where(a => colorList.Contains(a.Color)).Count();
```

Another version

```
var blueRedGreenBikes = GetBikes(filter).Count(s => colorList.Contains(s.Color));
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks!